# Has anyone or selenoid itself handles failing node in the cluster during a test execution?

Tags: selenoid

We have been runnning the selenoid cluster on Ec2 Spot instances and sometimes they are deleted. The test fails. Any recommended strategy to not be in this situation other than not using spot?

Answer (score 0):

Just use another project called [Ggr](https://aerokube.com/ggr/latest/). It will at least prevent new session requests from going to deleted node. Any tests running on the node while it is deleted will still be broken.

Comment: We already use ggr. I am talking about the instance failing during the test execution. does ggr handle that too?